# Program won't see the problems I want it to

Tags: java, string, for-loop, boolean, charat

This is part of a basic program I have. I'm trying to work on preventing errors or wrong information from going through. So in this part of the code, I set it up where the user enters their name, but if it contains numbers or symbols, it's supposed to return an error until something appropriate is entered. However, this only works sometimes. I can't figure out any sort of pattern as to when it will or won't work. The only thing I've notices is that the longer it is, the more likely it is to pass by.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Challenge1Easy
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
        String name, username;
        int age;
        boolean good = false;

        System.out.print("What's your name? ");
        name = reader.nextLine();

        String[] name1 = name.split("");

        do
        {
            System.out.print("Sorry, your \"name\" has characters that aren't letters in it. Please enter a real name. ");
            name = reader.nextLine();

            String[] name2 = name.split("");

            for (int i = 0; i < name.length(); i++)
            {
                if(!Character.isLetter(name.charAt(i)))
                {
                    good = false;
                }

                else
                {
                    good = true;
                }
            }
        }

        while(good != true);
```

I looked at some different questions on here and pulled some of the information from those questions/answers and tried to implement it in my program, but clearly something didn't work. What am I doing wrong that sometimes it will catch it, but other times it won't? Entering something like `Man99` will cause the prompt to enter a new name to come up. However, entering something like `khewriuhweiuf8489358934589734985345hiewf` won't activate it.

Please disregard any unused variables. They're used later in the program, but don't affect what I posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a moment to read through your `for-loop`, read it outload if you have to...

```
for (int i = 0; i < name.length(); i++)
{
    if(!Character.isLetter(name.charAt(i)))
    {
        good = false;
    }

    else
    {
        good = true;
    }
}
```

Assuming that `name` looks something like `N1NANA`...

- `i = 0`, `name.charAt(i) = 'N'`, `good == true`
- `i = 1`, `name.charAt(i) = '1'`, `good == false`
- `i = 2`, `name.charAt(i) = 'N'`, `good == true`

... Well there's a problem...if the last character in the name is valid, `good` will always be `true`

Instead, the moment you hit an invalid character, you should set the `good` flag to `false` and stop processing the rest of the text, for example...

```
good = true;
for (int i = 0; i < name.length(); i++)
{
    if(!Character.isLetter(name.charAt(i)))
    {
        good = false;
        break;
    }
}
```

Now, if you want to do something really simple, you could use something like...

```
good = text.matches("[a-zA-Z]");
```

This will return `true` only if the `name` contains characters between `a-z` in either case.  Obviously, this precludes things like `_`, but you could expand the idea to meet more requirements...

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
boolean good = true;
do
{

    for (int i = 0; i < name.length(); i++)
    {
        if(!Character.isLetter(name.charAt(i)))
        {
            good = false;
            break;
        }

        else
        {
            continue;
        }
    }

    if (!good) {
        System.out.print("Sorry, your \"name\" has characters that aren't letters in it. Please enter a real name. ");
        name = reader.nextLine();
    }
}

while(good != true);
```